# Dialog box error in asynctask

Tags: java, android, progressdialog, android-asynctask

When I try to show a working dialog for an asynctask i get the following errors:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
java.lang.NullPointerException

The code of the activity and asynctask is:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ControlLogin ctlLogin;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        ctlLogin = (ControlLogin)findViewById(R.id.controlLogin);

        ctlLogin.setOnLoginListener(new OnLoginListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onLogin(String email, String password, Boolean saveAccount){


            ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
            dialog.setMessage("Signing...");
            dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            dialog.setCancelable(false);

            new Login().execute(email, password);
        }
    });



    }

    public class Login extends AsyncTask<String, Float, CloudApp> {

        protected void onPreExecute(){
            dialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected CloudApp doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            CloudApp api = new CloudAppImpl(arg0[0], arg0[1]);
            return api;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(CloudApp api){

            dialog.dismiss();
            try {
                CloudAppAccount acc = api.getAccountDetails();
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "test: " + acc.getEmail(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            } catch (CloudAppException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Any help??? Thanks!!

Comment: You should post the stacktrace for the NullPointerException.

Comment: How can I get the stacktrace?

Comment: get error log from DDMS -> Logcat window

Comment: Stacktrace is unnecessary, nicholas.hauschild solved the problem below.  Make sure you hit the check mark next to his answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are hiding your member `dialog` in your code by defining a local variable `dialog` in your `onLogin(...)` method.  Because of this, `dialog` is never initialized to anything and that is why you get an NPE in your `Login` class.

```
    @Override
    public void onLogin(String email, String password, Boolean saveAccount){

        //remove the leading ProgessDialog here...it is hiding your member 'dialog'
        //dialog = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
        ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
        dialog.setMessage("Signing...");
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);

        new Login().execute(email, password);
    }
```

Comment: I've remove the line and it fails again

Comment: Don't remove the line, remove the first word of the line...I have edited my post...

Comment: ok, Now the error is:
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Comment: Well, that sounds like it should be a new question, as it seems that this one is solved.  Have you researched this new exception on your own yet?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your dialog exist when you dismiss it? I think in the onLogin you recreate a new dialog variable with the same name as your activity field variable.

```
protected void onPostExecute(CloudApp api) {

            dialog.dismiss(); // this one is not initialized
            try {
                CloudAppAccount acc = api.getAccountDetails();
```

You might play safe:

```
 if (dialog != null) dialog.dismiss();
```